# Angular 4.3 Interceptors for Lazy Loaded Modules

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular-http-interceptors

What is the best practice to use core module service in lazy loaded feature module and  feature child modules.
As per Angular style guide I have the following

```
 app
   -core
       - core.module.ts
       -logger.service.ts
       -token-interceptor.service.ts
       -authentication.service.ts
   -shared
       -shared.module.ts
   -base module (my feature base , lazy loaded with router-outlet)
     -base.module.ts
     -base.routing.module.ts
     -base
       -base.component.ts
     -admin (lazy loaded , child module of base module)
      -admin.module.ts
      -admin.routing.ts
      -admin-component.ts 
     -report(lazy loaded , child module of base module, sibling of admin)
      -report.module.ts
      -report.routing.ts
      -report-component.ts
```

If I add TokenInterceptorService as a provider in all feature module,then HTTP interceptor works.
When I add it in App module,(but not in lazy loaded feature module) it does not intercept http request triggered in lazy loaded feature module.

What is the best practice,  of using services/interceptor   declared in core module.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,BrowserAnimationsModule, CoreModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule
  ], providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptorService, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'base', pathMatch: 'full' },                   
            {  path: 'base', loadChildren: 'app/base/base.module#BaseModule'  }            
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

core.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, HttpModule,  
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [LoggerService, AuthenticationService]
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
  }
}
```

token-interceptor.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

    import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {


      constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('Adding authorization header')

        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: { authorization: this.auth.getToken() }
        });
        console.log('Added authorization header')
        return next.handle(request).do(event => { }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log("Error ===>", err);
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          } else if (err.status == 401) {

            console.log('Status 401  unautorized');
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
          }

          return Observable.throw(new Error('Your custom error'));
        });;
      }

    }
```

base.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule, BaseRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [BaseComponent],
      providers: [],
    })
    export class BaseModule {


      constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: BaseModule) {

        if (parentModule) {
          throw new Error(
            'BaseModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
        }
      }
    }
```

base.routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '', component: BaseComponent,
                children: [

                    { path: '', redirectTo: 'admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/base/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },                         
                ]
            }])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class BaseRoutingModule {
}
```

admin.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, AdminRoutingModule,BusyModule
  ],
  declarations: [UserListComponent, UserComponent, MenuListComponent, MenuComponent, CodeListComponent, CodeComponent],
  providers: [CodeService, UserService, MenuService,{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptorService, multi: true }]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

admin.routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([

            {
                path: '',
                children: [
                    { path: '', redirectTo:'code-list', pathMatch: 'full'  },
                    { path: 'code-list', component: CodeListComponent },
                    { path: 'code/:id', component: CodeComponent },

                    { path: 'user-list', component: UserListComponent },
                    { path: 'user/:id', component: UserComponent },

                    { path: 'menu-list', component: MenuListComponent },
                    { path: 'menu/:id', component: MenuComponent },                    
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: could you provide your lazy loaded module ts file? I think you've added `CoreModule` to imports array in your lazy loaded module that you have not to do

Comment: @DanilGudz added code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to create a provider for your interceptor. 
You should export your `CoreModule` with `forRoot()`:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [],
      {enableTracing: true}
    ),
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: 'Window', useValue: window},
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true},
        SORT_TYPES_PROVIDER,
        ApiService,
        AnimationService,
        BillingService,
        UserService,
        ...
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Then import it in your `AppModule` and forget about `CoreModule` imports at all. This is only one place it has to be explicitly used. All your lazy loaded modules will take your services etc by DI.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    FeaturesModule,
    PublicModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Also you don't need to create a separate routing module for each module. Just export what RouterModule.forChild returns and use it in `imports` of your module that needs it.

```js
export const publicRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: SignInComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'LGN_TL'
    },
    canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: GlobalComponent,
    loadChildren: '../protected/protected.module#ProtectedModule',
    canLoad: [AuthCanLoadGuard]
  },
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
]);
```

UPD. suggestion for routing not a styleguide. Use `RoutingModule` as before (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#angular-ngmodule-names)

Comment: it is not working, I exported  CoreModule, but request are not intercepted.

Comment: In angular https://angular.io/guide/router ,  each router file is defined as module. (AppRoutingModule,HeroRoutingModule ), you suggest  to export RouterModule.forChild , while both works for me but  I don't know  the pros and cons between them

Comment: oh, it's okay for routing. Found in styleguides https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#angular-ngmodule-names . `CoreModule` has to include all the providers. There should be defined an interceptor. And only one place you have to import `CoreModule` is `AppModule` and you don't need to create another providers for existing interceptor in `CoreModule`. Also you have to remove `HttpClientModule` from every submodules. It causes not to intercept your requests as your submodule use a new instance of `HttpClientModule`.

Comment: If you want to use services from this module it will be injected from dependencies tree from `AppModule` that has import for `CoreModule` that has `HttpClientModule` import. Look in my example. Import `HttpClientModule` only in `CoreModule`

Comment: Thanks, your solution saved my day