# How to add interceptors to app.module conditionally?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I read other topics but none of them reflects my problem.
Background first - we got an Angular App which works in two modes - in first mode applications uses one API and in the second one - another one.

This, what I want to achieve is to have Http Interceptors only in second mode.

So, is there a way to add Http Interceptors conditionally, depends on some APP_CONFIG file or environment prop?

I created kind of setInterceptors() helper function which adds those interceptors, depends on condition, to providers array but it fails during build with message:

> Function calls are not supported in decorators

Comment: Why you just don't inject interceptor on app level, but inside it to check if some APP_CONFIG === something then execute it?

Comment: Not sure, if I understand. Can you provide some (pseudo) code as an example?

Comment: For example you have HttpInterceptor, inject it in app.module.ts then inside HttpInterceptor in intercept or some other function on beggining check if (environment.app === "develop") return;

Comment: Do you have 2 separate modules for 2 modes?

Comment: @AdritaSharma Nope. That's the problem

Comment: @N.Tasikj Ah, this way. Well, problem is, we don't want to have those whole Interceptors related logic in bundle when it's not needed (it's quite big anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 seperate modules for 2 modes, and then inject it in the required module provider.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: YourModule
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
}
```

Here `YourModule` is the module in which you want to apply interceptor

Comment: Hmm, I'm unable to initialize Interceptors in any module besides app.module. Like they are completely invisible in lazy loaded modules. :-(

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009490/angular-4-3-interceptors-for-lazy-loaded-modules